# Is this relationship, $\sum^{\infty}_{N=1}\frac{N^{-\alpha} \, x^{N-1}}{\Gamma(N)}\sim e^{x}x^{-\alpha}$, true?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, power-series

According to numerical simulation, the relationship
$$\sum^{\infty}_{N=1}\frac{N^{-\alpha} \, x^{N-1}}{\Gamma(N)}\sim e^{x}x^{-\alpha}$$
where $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function seems to be true.

Do you have any idea how to show this relationship using asymptotic or exact methods?

Comment: Given that $\Gamma(N) = (N-1)!$, why do you complicate the notation and not use the factorial?

Comment: This is because it is not always necessary for me to get exact solution. I thus wrote factorial function with a generalized form.

Comment: When you say $\sim$, you should also specify more: for example "as $x \to +\infty$".

Comment: What is $\alpha$: an arbitrary real number (then why write $-\alpha$ instead of $\alpha$?), a nonnegative real number, or something else?

Comment: ``When you say ∼, you should also specify more: for example "as x→+∞". '': Yes. I want to know asymptotic behavior "as x→+∞".

Comment: ``What is α: an arbitrary real number (then why write −α instead of α?), a nonnegative real number, or something else?'': I am sorry for not writing its setting. We assume $\alpha$ to be a positive real number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put $\mu:=\alpha-1$; then $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{ x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!n^\alpha} = x^{-1}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{ x^n}{n!n^\mu}=x^{-3/2}I_\mu(x)$ for the function $I_\mu(x)$ given in Johannes Trost’s answer to [Asymptotic expansion of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{n!{\sqrt{n}} }$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264595/asymptotic-expansion-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-fracx2n1n-sqrtn/266265#266265), with a complete asymptotic series.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me an answer and literature.

Answer (score 4):

Let $b:=-\alpha\in\mathbb C$. We have to show that
$$f(x):=\sum^{\infty}_{N=1}\frac{N^b \, x^{N-1}}{\Gamma(N)}\sim e^{x}x^b \tag{1}$$
as $x\to\infty$.

Let $Y=Y_x$ denote a random variable with the Poisson distribution with parameter $x$. Using the idea of [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/266178/36721), we have
$$f(x)=e^x x^b\, E\Big(\frac{Y+1}x\Big)^b. \tag{2}$$
Next, $\dfrac{Y+1}x\to1$ in probability (as $x\to\infty$), and $EY(Y-1)\cdots(Y-(k-1))=x^k$ and hence $EY^k\sim x^k$ for all natural $k$. So, by the uniform integrability of $\big(\frac{Y+1}x\big)^b$ (see e.g. the [de la Vallée-Poussin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability#Relevant_theorems)),
$$E\Big(\frac{Y+1}x\Big)^b\to1.$$
Thus, (1) follows from (2).

---

The uniform integrability of $\big(\frac{Y+1}x\big)^b$ also follows because
$$E\exp\frac{Y+1}x=\exp\Big\{\frac1x+x(e^{1/x}-1)\Big\}\to e<\infty.$$