# On convergence of entire functions

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables

Suppose we have a sequence of entire functions $f_n$ such that $$\text{$f_n(z)\to0$ for each natural $z$}\tag{1}$$
(as $n\to\infty$).

Is it possible to give general additional conditions on the sequence $(f_n)$ ensuring that (1) implies
$$\text{$f_n(z)\to0$ for each complex $z$?}\tag{2}$$

As a minimum, I would like such general additional conditions to hold and be easily verifiable when
$$f_n(z)=-1+\frac1{n^z}\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^z\,\frac{n^k}{k!}\,e^{-n};$$
cf. [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/404024/36721).

Comment: Did you try interpolational results like Ramanujan Master theorem?

Comment: @FedorPetrov : Thank you for your comment. I did not know of the Ramanujan Master theorem -- will try to learn about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited.

1. For your general question,
   one sufficient condition is that your functions are of exponential type $<\pi$.
   This is best possible since anything convergent to $\sin\pi z$ would be a counterexample, and $\sin\pi z$ has exponential type exactly $\pi$.

One can slightly improve this. For example when all $L^2(R)$ norms of your functions are bounded, independently of $n$. Then one can apply the Sampling theorem (which is usually credited to Nyquist in the West and Kotelnikov in the former Soviet Union, but in fact goes back to Cauchy), which estimates the
$L^2(R)$ norm in terms of $\ell^2(Z)$ norm, provided that the exponential
type is $\leq\pi$.

2. However your specific function does not have finite exponential type,
   so these general results will not work, and you need to use some specific properties of your function. You say that yout functions satisfy $f_n(z)\to 0$ for every integer $z$. Why is this so, and why your proof does not work for non-integer $z$?

Comment: Good point about the maximum modulus argument. Could you please provide details or references on the exponential type $<\pi$ being sufficient?

Comment: For the first paragraph, the keyword is "Jensen's formula", and a reference is Boris Ya. Levin (any of his two books). For the second paragraph, for example, G. Holland, Fourier Analysis and its applications, sect. 7.3, Sampling theorem.

Comment: Thank you for the references. Concerning the maximum modulus argument, now I am having a second thought: in view of of the term $-1$, how to show that the maximum modulus in $|z|\le r$ is achieved at $z=r$?

Comment: Also, I have found "2.3 The Jensen formula" in Levin's book, but it is about counts of zeroes, and I don't see how to use it here.

Comment: Also, "The Sampling Theorem" in G. Folland, Fourier Analysis and its applications, sect. 7.3, provides an expression for $f(t)$ (for real $t$?) as an infinite linear combination of the values of $f$ on a lattice in $\mathbb R$. But I am not sure how to use this to prove the convergence, even on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: This expression is valid for all complex $t$ since both sides are entire functions. The series converges in $L^2(R)$ and locally uniformly in $C$.

Comment: Sorry, Holland is a cookbook-style textbook for engineers. A more mathematical reference is this: https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1985-12-01/S0273-0979-1985-15293-0/S0273-0979-1985-15293-0.pdf I hope it explains everything about sampling theorem.

Comment: The paper by Higgins is certainly interesting. However, the sampling theorems are identities, not limit theorems. So, it is unclear to me how to use sampling theorems to get the convergence even for $f_n$'s of exponential type $<\pi$. More importantly, since the functions of interest are not of a finite exponential type, do you have a response to my previous comment about the maximum modulus argument?

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: The main part of them is that $\| f(x)\|^2=\| f(n)\|^2$, where the norm is $L^2(R)$ in the left hand side and $\ell_2(Z)$ in the RHS. Therefore if RHS tends to $0$ then the LHS also does.

Comment: All right. Still, the functions of interest are not of a finite exponential type, and so, the sampling theorems will not work for them. Do you have a response to my previous comment about the maximum modulus argument?

Comment: Yes, and I did notice this in my answer. But for your functions the elementary argument with max modulus was given. I do not see your comment on max modulus. And still do not see.

Comment: That was in my second comment: "in view of of the term $−1$, how to show that the maximum modulus in $|z|≤r$ is achieved at $z=r$?"

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: I actually did not notice that minus in front of 1. Have to think about it.

Comment: For this reason, the third paragraph of my answer is wrong, but the system does not allow me to delete it since it is accepted.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: Why $f_n(m)\to 0$ for each integer $m$?

Comment: I don't understand your question "Why $f_n(m)\to0$ for each integer  $m$?".  I did not say that. I said that one of the assumptions was that $f_n(z)\to0$ for each natural $z$.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: why $f_n(z)\to 0$ for each natural $z$?

Comment: "why $f_n(z)\to0$ for each natural $z$?" -- This is just an assumption. This assumption is easily checked for the particular $f_n$'s as in the last display in the question, by first doing the easy exact calculation with $k(k-1)\cdots(k+1-z)$ instead of $k^z$. (For simplicity, I have now replaced $((k+1)/n)^z$ there by $(k/n)^z$.)